# Highstock | Tooltip displacement | Tooltip content picks previous day's data on current day tooltip when zoomed in

Tags: highcharts

**Expected behaviour**

Tooltip content on a particular day should remain same even if the content is zoomed in or zoomed out.

**Actual behaviour**

Tooltip content on same day is different when graph is zoomed in and zoomed out.

**Live demo with steps to reproduce**

https://jsfiddle.net/aveohsdr/8/

**Github Issue Link**

https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/6241

**Affected browser(s)**

Firefox / Chrome

**Description**

Check tool-tip content for date 4th June 2016, and then change dates from range selector i.e 1 June 2016 to 30th June 2016, mouse hover on to 4th June tool-tip, now tool-tip has different content. Something's wrong with my code or may be at Highchart's end and I'm unable to figure out what.

**Code is below**

```
var seriesOptions = [];
$(function() {
var html = '';
var groupingButtons = {
        "Day": "day",
        "Week": "week",
        "Month":"month",
        "3M":"quater",
        "6M":"half"
};
for (var i in groupingButtons) {
    html += '<button class="btn btn-default dateWiseCriteria" data-criteria="' + groupingButtons[i] + '">' + i + '</button>';
}

$('.dateWiseCriteriaContainer').html(html);
var options = {};
$.extend(options, {
    units: [
        ['week', [1]]
    ]
});
drawAnalyticalStockChart(getSeries(), options);
$(document).on('click', '.dateWiseCriteria', function() {
    var options = {};
    var criteria = $(this).data('criteria') == 'quater' ? 'month' : $(this).data('criteria');
    criteria = $(this).data('criteria') == 'half' ? 'month' : criteria;
    var value = $(this).data('criteria') == 'quater' ? 3 : 1;
    value = $(this).data('criteria') == 'half' ? 6 : value;
    $.extend(options, {
        units: [
            [criteria, [value]]
        ]
    });
    drawAnalyticalStockChart(getSeries(), options);
});
});

function drawAnalyticalStockChart(series, options) {
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
    chart: {
        zoomType: 'x',
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    rangeSelector: {
        selected: 4
    },

    legend: {
        enabled: true
    },

    scrollbar: {
        showFull: false
    },

    xAxis: [{
        crosshair: true,
    }],

    yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: { //force all formats to be hour:minute:second
            second: '%H:%M:%S',
            minute: '%H:%M:%S',
            hour: '%H:%M:%S',
            day: '%H:%M:%S',
            week: '%H:%M:%S',
            month: '%H:%M:%S',
            year: '%H:%M:%S'
        },
        labels: {
            formatter: function() {
                //get the timestamp
                var time = this.value;
                return _format_date(time, 1);
                //now manipulate the timestamp as you wan using data functions
            },
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2]
            },
            x: 42
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Average Resolution Time',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2]
            },
            margin: 53
        },
        opposite: true

    }, { // Secondary yAxis
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Cases',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
            }
        },
        labels: {
            format: '{value} Cases',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
            }
        },
        allowDecimals: false,
        opposite: false

    }, { // Tertiary yAxis
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Average Response Time',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3]
            }
        },
        labels: {
            formatter: function() {
                //get the timestamp
                var time = this.value;
                return _format_date(time, 0, 1);
                //now manipulate the timestamp as you wan using data functions
            },
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3]
            }
        },
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: { //force all formats to be hour:minute:second
            second: '%H:%M:%S',
            minute: '%H:%M:%S',
            hour: '%H:%M:%S',
            day: '%H:%M:%S',
            week: '%H:%M:%S',
            month: '%H:%M:%S',
            year: '%H:%M:%S'
        },
    }],
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            var points = this.points;
            var groupingFormat = points[0].series.options.dataGrouping.dateTimeLabelFormats[points[0].series.currentDataGrouping.unitName][0];
            var headerFormat = '<span style="font-size: 10px">' + Highcharts.dateFormat(groupingFormat, this.x) + '</span><br/>';

            var pointFormat = '',
                currentYear;

            var isAllPointsHaveData = [];
            points.forEach(function(point) {
                if(point.y > 0) {
                    isAllPointsHaveData.push(1);
                }
            });

            points.forEach(function(point) {
                var name = point.series.name,
                    part;
                var finalValue = point.y;
                var showOnTooltip = true;
                if (name === 'Current Year') {
                    currentYear = part = new Date(point.x).getFullYear();
                } else if (name === 'Previous Year') {
                    part = new Date(point.x).getFullYear() - 1
                } else if (name === 'Average Response Time') {
                    finalValue = _format_date(point.y, 0, 1, 1);
                    part = (typeof currentYear !== 'undefined' ?  name + ' ('+currentYear+')' : name );
                } else {
                    finalValue = _format_date(point.y, 1, 1, 1);
                    part = (typeof currentYear !== 'undefined' ?  name + ' ('+currentYear+')' : name );
                }
                if(!$.isEmptyObject(isAllPointsHaveData)) {
                    pointFormat += '<span style="color:' + point.color + '">\u25CF</span> <p style="color:' + point.color + '">' + part + '</p>: <b>' + finalValue + ' ' + point.series.tooltipOptions.valueSuffix + '</b><br/>';
                }
            });
            return headerFormat + pointFormat;
        },
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            showInNavigator: true,
            dataGrouping: {
                dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                    millisecond: ['%A, %b %e, %H:%M:%S.%L', '%A, %b %e, %H:%M:%S.%L', '-%H:%M:%S.%L'],
                    second: ['%A, %b %e, %H:%M:%S', '%A, %b %e, %H:%M:%S', '-%H:%M:%S'],
                    minute: ['%A, %b %e, %H:%M', '%A, %b %e, %H:%M', '-%H:%M'],
                    hour: ['%A, %b %e, %H:%M', '%A, %b %e, %H:%M', '-%H:%M'],
                    day: ['%A, %b %e, %Y', '%A, %b %e', '-%A, %b %e, %Y'],
                    week: ['Week from %A, %b %e, %Y', '%A, %b %e', '-%A, %b %e, %Y'],
                    month: ['%B %Y', '%B', '-%B %Y'],
                    year: ['%Y', '%Y', '-%Y']
                },
                enabled: true,
                forced: true,
                units: options.units,
                smoothed: true,
            }
        }
    },

    series: getSeries()
});
}
function getSeries() {
seriesOptions = [{
    name: 'Previous Year',
    type: 'column',
    yAxis: 1,
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ' Case(s)',
    },
    data: [],
    "dataGrouping": {
        "approximation": "sum"
    },
    "color": "#8085E9"
}, {
    name: 'Current Year',
    type: 'column',
    yAxis: 1,
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ' Case(s)',
    },
    data: [],
    "dataGrouping": {
        "approximation": "sum"
    },
    "color": "#F45B5B"
}, {
    name: 'Average Response Time',
    type: 'spline',
    yAxis: 2,
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: '',
    },
    data: [],
    "dataGrouping": {
        approximation: function(arr) {
            var groupedData = [];
            var xyDataWithTimestamps = [];
            var t = this;
            this.xData.forEach(function(xd, i) {
                xyDataWithTimestamps.push([
                    xd,
                    t.yData[i]
                ]);
            });

            var groupedDataWithTimestamps = [];
            for(var i in arr) {
                var arr1 = jQuery.grep(xyDataWithTimestamps, function( a ) {
                      return a[1] == arr[i];
                });
                groupedDataWithTimestamps.push([
                    arr1[0][0],
                    arr1[0][1]
                ]);
            }

            var len = arr.length;
            var seconds = [], cases = [];
            var finalArrayWithData = [];
            for(var i in groupedDataWithTimestamps) {
                if(groupedDataWithTimestamps[i][1] > 0) {
                    var date = _format_date(arr[i], 1, 1, 1, true);
                    seconds.push((((date.d * 24) * 60) * 60) + ((date.h * 60) * 60) + (date.m * 60));
                    var arr2 = jQuery.grep(seriesOptions[1].data, function( a ) {
                      return a[0] == groupedDataWithTimestamps[i][0];
                    });
                    cases.push(arr2[0][1]);
                    finalArrayWithData['s'] = seconds;
                    finalArrayWithData['cases'] = cases;
                }
            }
            var sumTopS = 0;
            var sumBottom = 0;
            console.log(finalArrayWithData);
            for (var i in finalArrayWithData['cases']) {
                if(finalArrayWithData['s'][i] > 0) {
                    sumTopS += finalArrayWithData['cases'][i] * finalArrayWithData['s'][i];
                    sumBottom += finalArrayWithData['cases'][i];
                }
            }

            var averageS = 0;
            if ($.isNumeric(sumTopS) && sumBottom) {
                averageS = Math.round(sumTopS / sumBottom);
            }

            _dts = Date.UTC(1970, 0, 1, 0, 0, averageS) / 1000;
            return _dts;
        }
    },
    "color": "#8BA6C7"
}];
return seriesOptions;
}
function _format_date(ts, d = 0, h = 0, m = 0, getArray = false) {
var date_now = 0;
var label = '';
var date_future = ts * 1000;
var dateArray = [];
// get total seconds between the times
var delta = Math.abs(date_future - date_now) / 1000;

// calculate (and subtract) whole days
var days = Math.floor(delta / 86400);
var finalValue = '';
if (d) {
    label = days > 1 ? ' days ' : ' day ';
    dateArray['d'] = days;
    finalValue += days + label;
}

delta -= days * 86400;

// calculate (and subtract) whole hours
var hours = Math.floor(delta / 3600) % 24;
if (h) {
    if (d == 0) {
        var totalHours = hours + (days * 24);
        label = totalHours > 1 ? ' hours ' : ' hour ';
        dateArray['h'] = totalHours;
        finalValue += totalHours + label;
    } else {
        label = hours > 1 ? ' hours ' : ' hour ';
        dateArray['h'] = hours;
        finalValue += hours + label;
    }
}

// calculate (and subtract) whole minutes
var minutes = Math.floor(delta / 60) % 60;
delta -= minutes * 60;

if (m) {
    label = minutes > 1 ? ' minutes ' : ' minute ';
    dateArray['m'] = minutes;
    finalValue += minutes + label;
}

if(getArray) {
    return dateArray;
}
return finalValue;
}
```

Comment: I can see that it happens only when the column is on the edges - it looks like inconsistency between grouping of columns and lines http://jsfiddle.net/kfz3ow4q/1/ - but it appears only when the smoothed property is enabled. http://jsfiddle.net/kfz3ow4q/2/

Comment: @morganfree Yes, I'm now curious to know the exact usage of smoothed = true. Do you have any reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to this question from github is:

`smoothed = false;`

[click here for reference](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.series.dataGrouping.smoothed)